# $A_n$ as a Galois group

Tags: galois-theory

I am looking for a clear, detailed proof that the alternating group $A_n$ is realizable as a Galois group over the rationals $Q$. (I have seen proofs using Hilbert's irreducibility theorem, but they are sketchy.)

Comment: See [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inverse_Galois_problem#Alternating_groups).